# Codeigniter can not redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

i am trying to learn codeigniter, and i start with basic login function. Everything works well, until i want to redirect member to their homepage.
i seems like codeigniter can not redirect to it. It just always stops at this url:

[image]

I want this redirect to the site/members_area like mycode. This is my controller code:

```
class login extends ci_controller{
function index(){
    $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
    $this->load->view('includes/template.php', $data);
}
function validate_credentials(){
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

        if($query)//user's credentails validated
        {
             $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true);
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('site/members_area');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

}

And this is my model code:

```
class Membership_model extends ci_model{
function validate(){
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('membership');

    if($query->num_rows == 1){
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

I already input helper url and form in my autoload, but it still does not work.
Can someone help?

Comment: in your model change `if($query->num_rows == 1){` to `if($query->num_rows > 0) {`

Comment: Also do not use MD5 for password hashing it is very unsecured use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php for hashing and this for verify  http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: i did change from == 1 to >0 but nothing change. i mean my code still is not runnable.
I know that md5 is not good for password, this one is just an practice for codeigniter.

Comment: `Login`, `CI_Controller`, `CI_Model`.

Comment: still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`num_rows` is a function and should have parentheses like this: `$query->num_rows()`

You can eliminate the if and simply use

```
return $query->num_rows() > 0;
```